# Decomposition of 4/73

Tags: number-theory

I want to find 3 natural  numbers  a, b and c such that 
$\frac{4}{73}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Sirous Did you mean $\dfrac{4}{73}=\dfrac{1}{a+\dfrac{1}{b+\dfrac{1}{c}}}$?

Comment: No. The problem is clear

Comment: You can find a solution with all $a,b,c$ at most $1000$ easily by writing a short script in pretty much any programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of an Erdős–Straus conjecture.
$$\frac{4}{73}=\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{219}+\frac{1}{4380}$$

Comment: I need the decomposition  of 4/193 and 4/313 for check my research on Erdos-Straus problem. If it is possible please help me.